# Package private access modifier

Tags: java

If a class has the visibility package private, is there any point to also set the methods to have that visibility since you can't access the methods in the first place?

Comment: Short answer is no, there is no point.

Comment: It could prevent the access to these method in the future if the visibility of the class is changed in the future,

Comment: Yes, there is a point.  Someone might be able to get at the methods via reflection if they’re public, even running under a SecurityManager which prohibits `setAccessible` calls.  In general, if something isn’t intended for public use, don’t make it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package private class for example may implement some interface and be used outside of its package. In that case implemented methods should be `public`. Also you might what to restrict usage of some members in the same package by `private` access modifier.

```
package pkg1;

public interface SomeInterface {
    void m();

    public static SomeInterface getImplementation() {
        return new A();
    }
}

class A implements SomeInterface {
    @Override
    public void m() {}

    public void m2() {} // this one cannot be called from other packages

    private void m3() {} // this one might be used only in class A
}

package pkg2;

import pkg1.SomeInterface;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeInterface implementation = SomeInterface.getImplementation();
        implementation.m();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer yes if a class is going to be  implemented or extend. No if it is not going to be extend or implemented. How ever I highly recommend to still make methods or variables you don't want other classes to see be private. This will save time later on if you wish to change the classes visiablity, along with making the code more readable in the long run.